# Android: Getting shared preferences crashes app

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

I have the following activity which extends ListActivity:

```
public class TweetActivity extends ListActivity {

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("NewsTweetSettings", 0);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
  }
}
```

The line where I set the sharePreferences always causes the app to crash in the emulator, and I can't find a reason why. Any ideas?

Comment: use the line in your oncreate() after calling the constructor . It may help you

Comment: put `settings = this.getSharedPreferences("NewsTweetSettings", 0);` after `super....`

Comment: These guys have it. Consider this: where that line is, you haven't even executed your constructor. There is no `this`.

Comment: Thanks that did it! Is there a particular reason why it needs to be done like this? @G_S if you write it as an answer I will mark it correct since you were the first to suggest it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the line in your oncreate() after calling the onCreate() super class implementation . It may help you

```
public class TweetActivity extends ListActivity {

    SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings=this.getSharedPreferences("NewsTweetSettings", 0); 
    ....
  }
}
```

The reason is we dont have any value for 'this' before the line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

call this method `this.getSharedPreferences("NewsTweetSettings", 0);` in your `OnCreate`..like

```
public class TweetActivity extends ListActivity {

    SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings=this.getSharedPreferences("NewsTweetSettings", 0); 
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however G_S found the solution before as a comment :) thanks all the same